# Official SDK/API for Mi and other smart Band

Tags: android, health-monitoring, mi

We want to develop an android application to support MiBand and Other Smart bands. We want to fetch information like Heart rate etc. from Smart Band via BLE and display it in a mobile application.

How can we get that information from the device? Is there any official SDK or API for it?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no official SDK/API for Mi and some of other smart bands. We do have official SDK/API for Fitbit, Polar, Garmin, Misfit Shine, Lumo run, etc. For Mi Band, Amazfit Bip you can refer this reference project - https://github.com/Freeyourgadget/Gadgetbridge.

Answer (score 8):

There's also a huami tech GitHub repository which describes their API, You'll need to register your app with them through email it seems.

https://github.com/huamitech/rest-api/wiki

Comment: I seen issues that they are not accepting app, is it working for you?

Answer (score 6):

I found this but it's on Chinese: https://dev.mi.com/docs/micloud/health/