# Sending notification to Mi Band 5 from Android app

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, sdk, xiaomi

I want to develop a simple application which sends custom notifications from android phone. Is there any open source SDK for Mi Band 5 for that?

Is that possible to create watch face which displays a value from custom datasource which is received from the phone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't anything that I know of that would allow you to customise the watch face on the Mi Band. There are a few SDK and applications that allow you to read/analyse the Mi Band's data, as well as perform additional tasks. Have a look at the links below:-

- [Official SDK/API for Mi and other smart band](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53775077/official-sdk-api-for-mi-and-other-smart-band)
- [Open source library for getting data off activity trackers](https://github.com/ictinnovaties-zorg/openwindesheart)
- [OpenWindesheart demo](https://github.com/ictinnovaties-zorg/openwindesheart-demo)
- [Mi Band Android SDK Test](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TJOM4tnhIG8)

Finally, note that when you connect to a Mi Band, you Android device is the GATT client and the Mi Band is the GATT server. Therefore, the notifications would be sent from band to the phone and not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Simply just decompile mi band controller apps, and find out how they works.

Answer (score 0):

There is plenty possible when it comes to what you are suggesting. Have a look at the geek doing website for modded firmware (just the watch face, and the res file). Same site will point you to watch face editors as will Amazing Watchfaces site.

And checkout the xdrip/nightnurse mod for miband on GitHub.

I just happened to be working on something similar as a personal project. ;-)