# How to Connect Xiaomi Smart Band 8 Active

Tags: android, flutter, web, bluetooth, xiaomi

I want to connect Xiaomi Smart Band 8 Active to  flutter mobile app.
I searched information that I could receive data by connecting via Bluetooth.
I am asking a question because it is difficult to obtain accurate facts.

Can the Xiaomi smart band obtain information such as heart rate and calorie consumption through Bluetooth connection (e.g. [flutter_blue](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue))?
Or do I need to use a specific SDK?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It isn't the issue of the connection.  I believe it's always BT based.  It's the issue of the protocol you need to communicate your flutter app with the smart band.  This would mean you'd need to find the SDK for that XiaoMi smartband.

Comment: Akin to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53775077/official-sdk-api-for-mi-and-other-smart-band

Comment: Can I refer to Huami Web API in the attached link?
Can I received data from smart band using this?

Comment: I have no clue, sorry.